# slds themes not applied in lightning communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightning-community

I  tried using **[slds themes](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/)** for applying a light gray background color to a certain section of my layout,, It works fine in LEX, however, I require this form to also be used in lightning communities. Imo, looks like a bug and Ill have to workaround with css no biggie.

```
    <lightning:layout class="slds-theme_shade" multipleRows="true">
      <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
        <lightning:layout class="slds-theme_shade">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                <p>Name</p>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">

                <p>Eligibltiy</p>

            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>

      </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">

                <p>Eligibltiy</p>

            </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>

<div class="slds-theme_shade">this should have a gray background</div>
```

at first I thought it might be an issue with lightning:layouts, but then it worked in lex, tried with a Div, same behavior....

Or is there some other themeing or slds background color class that can be applied, just to avoid adding css to the style sheet that works in communities?

(fyi: some of the other theme classes work)

Comment: Following. Have the same question about how to add the lightning style for VF in a community

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your lightning components into a `<div class="slds-scope"></div>'? I am pretty sure you have to do it in VF, and I wonder if it applies to the community as well. Haven't had a chance to test it out.